# make an array of item from another array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, linq

I have following array

```
var Fruits = [
  {
    "Name": "Apple,Orange",
    "id": "20"
  },
  {
     "Name": "Mango",
     "id": "40"
  }
];
```

I want to make a new array that contains Name of selected item whose id matches the given id. Something like we do in C# linq:

```
var givenId = 20
var newArray = fruits.Select(x=>x.Name).Where(y=>y.id == givenId)
```

so my newArray becomes ['Apple', 'Orange']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
 and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
 to do it.

Demo:

```js
var Fruits = [
  {
    "Name": "Apple,Orange",
    "id": "20"
  },
  {
     "Name": "Mango",
     "id": "40"
  }
];

var given_id = 20;

var result = Fruits.filter(val => val.id == given_id).map(val => val.Name);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use from something like this code :

```
var Fruits = [
{
    "Name": "Apple,Orange",
    "id": "20"
},
{
    "Name": "Mango",
    "id": "40"
}
];

findById = (id) =>{
   var result = [];
   Fruits.map((item,index)=>{
       if(item.id && item.id==id)
           return result.push(item);
   });
   return result;
}
```